# Parsing enum of Lists in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, enums, nested-lists

I have an enum of Lists defined as follows:

```
enum class Test(val type: List<String>){
  A(listOf<String>("aa", "ab", "ac")),
  B(listOf<String>("bb", "bc", "bd")),
  C(listOf<String>("aa", "bb", "dd"));
companion object {
            fun Search(type: String?): Boolean {
                val before = type?.substringBefore(".")?.toUpperCase()?.trim()
                val after = type?.substringAfter(".")?.toUpperCase()?.trim()
                return values().any { it.name == normalized }
            }
            fun ListAll(): List<String> {

            }
    }
}
```

and I need to perform two main operations, Search() and ListAll(). My input for Search operation is a string like "B.bd" and my output for ListAll operation should be

```
A.aa
A.ab
A.ac
B.bb
B.bc
B.bd
C.aa
C.bb
C.dd
```

I'm new to Kotlin and was wondering if there's any efficient way to return this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a viable implementation. Map all enums with their types to a `String` and store those as property. Then simply use string comparison to look up your search input:

```
enum class Test(val type: List<String>) {
    A(listOf("aa", "ab", "ac")),
    B(listOf("bb", "bc", "bd")),
    C(listOf("aa", "bb", "dd"));

    companion object {
        private val normalizedValues = values().flatMap { value ->
                value.type.map { "${value.name}.$it" }
            }
        fun listAll() = normalizedValues
        fun search(type: String?) = normalizedValues.contains(type)
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(Test.listAll())
    println(Test.search("B.bd"))
    println(Test.search("B.ad"))
}
```

Output:

```
[A.aa, A.ab, A.ac, B.bb, B.bc, B.bd, C.aa, C.bb, C.dd]
true
false
```

(Side note: I simplified your code a bit and used lowerCamelCase for function names. You could also directly use `normalizedValues` instead of `listAll()` but I decided to keep your existing signatures.)

Comment: This is great! What if I have a 4th row in the enum `D(listOf())` and I want it to pass true for any String after the . in search. Eg: "D.garbage"

Comment: Then it gets more complicated. Currently `D` wouldn't even show up in `listAll` and you would need to implement custom matching logic in `search`.